# SEO , Flash and data from external file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, seo, actionscript-2, actionscript-1

i have to create SWF that contains only specific parser and load text content from external file . How i can allow search engines to see this data under swf link ?

Can i put this data somehow to html or js without and penalty ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adobe [announced](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swf_searchability.html?devcon=f1) indexing of Flash content by Yahoo and Google in 2008.

Here you will find information ([old](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/06/improved-flash-indexing.html),[actual](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/06/flash-indexing-with-external-resource.html)) on how Google will handle Flash files.

If I understood this right, there is nothing special to do for the creator of the Flash file.
Only embedding the Flash file preferably without JavaScript and use AS 1, AS 2 or AS 3.

Another option is to use a NOSCRIPT section.

Comment: thanks . Im working on parser that execute AS3 code from XML form text and like to make sites indexed by search engines .

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old, but you may find it relevant.

http://www.metah.ch/blog/2008/04/holy-grail-seo-model-for-flash-and-flex-content/